# phantom indents after scale

Tags: javascript, vue.js

please tell me where the phantom indents come from after a click if height = 0;
This is not visible until the opening of the dropdown, only with the subsequent setting of zero height.
And also why the animation is so twitching ...
If you remove the scale, the animation will stop twitching, but the phantom indents of ~ 1px remain (why does it exist)
Most noticeable at 1360x768 resolution
[image: 1360x768 screenshot]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="vue">
    <div class="select">
      <div class="main" @mousedown="isDropped = !isDropped">
        <div class="option-main"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown" v-dropped>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="option">
            <span>English</span>
          </div>
          <div class="option">
            <span>Русский</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<style>
  body {
    background: green;
  }

  .select {
    width: max-content;
    height: max-content;

    transform-origin: top left;
      transform: scale(16);

    background: white;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.6vmin;
  }

  .main {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 2vmin;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .option-main {
    display: flex;
    height: 2vmin;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
  }

  .option {
    display: flex;
    height: 2vmin;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
  }

  .dropdown {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 1s ease;
    background: white;
  }

  .container {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .option-selected {
    background: red;
  }
</style>
<script>
  let myVue = new Vue({
    el: "#vue",
    data: {
      isDropped: false,
    },
    directives: {
      dropped(el, binding, vnode) {
        if (vnode.context.isDropped) {
          el.style.height =
            el.firstChild.scrollHeight + "px";
        } else {
          el.style.height = 0;
        }
      },
    },
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.select` element needs `overflow: hidden`:

```css
.select {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="vue">
    <div class="select">
      <div class="main" @mousedown="isDropped = !isDropped">
        <div class="option-main"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown" v-dropped>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="option">
            <span>English</span>
          </div>
          <div class="option">
            <span>Русский</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<style>
  body {
    background: green;
  }

  .select {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: max-content;
    height: max-content;

    transform-origin: top left;
      transform: scale(16);

    background: white;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.6vmin;
  }

  .main {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 2vmin;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .option-main {
    display: flex;
    height: 2vmin;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
  }

  .option {
    display: flex;
    height: 2vmin;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
  }

  .dropdown {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 1s ease;
    background: white;
  }

  .container {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .option-selected {
    background: red;
  }
</style>
<script>
  let myVue = new Vue({
    el: "#vue",
    data: {
      isDropped: false,
    },
    directives: {
      dropped(el, binding, vnode) {
        if (vnode.context.isDropped) {
          el.style.height =
            el.firstChild.scrollHeight + "px";
        } else {
          el.style.height = 0;
        }
      },
    },
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Can I please ask why this problem existed at all, if the height was 0